# How to get nodes from Neo4j through java code

Tags: java, neo4j

I want to load nodes from the neo4j to java code.

I tried all the way from google but it doesn't work. Can you help me by specific code?

Comment: Could you show us some code of your attempts?

Comment: try ( Transaction ignored = db.beginTx();
          Result result = db.execute( "match (n {name: 'my node'}) return n ,n.name" ) )
    {
        while ( result.hasNext() )
        {
            Map<String,Object> row = result.next();
            for ( Entry<String,Object> column : row.entrySet() )
            {
                rows += column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ";
            }
             rows += "\n";
         }
}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code from your comment

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information in the Neo4j manual and on the developer pages.

Please read there, and come back to ask if you have still questions:

- http://neo4j.com/developer/java
- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded.html
- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html#_sending_cypher